# Are 64 nested If/Else statements bad?

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a bit of a dilemma. I have to do some sorting of a list. There are 2 lists that users can select from and then select one of the elements in that list to sort on. Unfortunately for me, the second list is a child list, within the first list.

The child list will require slightly different logic other than if the user just chose from the parent list. I have the logic down to sort on either the parent and/or the child list using LINQ so I'm not too worried about the logic of it.

There is also the option to choose on ascending or descending order to make matter worse, at least for me. I've gone through the logic and it looks as though there will be a total of 64 if/else statements that I will need to use in order to incorporate all the scenarios.

My first reaction was that this wasn't a very good way to go about it as this seems like a lot of if/else statements. Is there a better way to go about this or do I just need to bite the bullet:

Logic for Parent:

```
Positions.Select(x => x.Product).OrderBy(x=>x.Price).AsQueryable();
```

Logic for Child:

```
Positions.Select(x => x.Product).OrderBy(x=>x.Performance.OrderBy(c=>c.AssortmentCategory).Select(c=>c.AssortmentCategory).FirstOrDefault()).AsQueryable();
```

Positions and Performance are both ListExtended's, if that matters. Also, I'm using the Dynamic LINQ library as I will be getting user input, though that is not shown above.

Edit1: I forgot to say this sorts only the parent list. Even if they choose an element from the child list, it will sort the parent list.

Comment: Using a lot of if/else might decrease performances but it's so minimal that it will never impact your program. If you wan't to make everybody happy you can just use switch statement.

Comment: Basically each conditional in your code (e.g. `if`, `case`) adds +1 to _Cyclomatic Complexity (CC)_, essentially _a measure of the amount of code paths in your code_.  Think of it as coming to a fork in a road.  Driving a car from A to B it's always nice to take that freeway rather than take the backstreets in suburbia.  The biggest impact a high measure of CC is to _unit tests_ because it means they have to consider _all the variations_ your code state can take. https://blog.ndepend.com/understanding-cyclomatic-complexity/

Comment: I can't quite see what you are talking about in my head (more code would be useful). I suspect that you might be able to build a dictionary (maybe dictionaries) of column names and composable query parts using something like Predicate Builder (http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) and build the query on the fly by looking something up (rather than building the logic through a maze of `if`/`else if` statements

Comment: The other big cyclomatic complexity hit is understandability and maintainability.  Don't worry about performance, worry about how complex your code will grow to.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a lookup dictionary that maps selection from first list (string, int ,? not sure what type you need) to a Func<> and do

```
var sortedData = sortDict[selected](args....)
```

Comment: ...and `Dictionary<>`s are wonderful for _collapsing_ all that otherwise cyclomatic complexity you get from multiple `if/else` into nothing. +1